# Do disaccharidases require a cofactor or coenzyme to function?

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, enzymes

I'm doing research on lactose intolerance and am curious if disaccharidases (enzymes that break down disaccharides) require a cofactor or coenzyme to function? Reviews or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most enzymes (especially ones catalyzing simply reactions like this) do not require cofactors or co-enzymes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that beta-glucosidases do not require co-factors but some alpha-glucosidases are co-factor dependent.

Some bacterial alpha-glucosidases (GH4 family) require NAD<sup>+</sup> to function ([Hall et al., 2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2767093/)). *Thermotoga maritama* alpha-glucosidase (GH4 family) requires Mn<sup>2+</sup>, in addition to NAD<sup>+</sup> to function ([Lodge et al., 2003](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12588867)). *Ferroplasma acidophilum* alpha-glucosidase seems to contain iron but its role as a co-factor is not known ([Ferrer et al., 2005](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1276924/)).

For more information on alpha-glucosidases see [BRENDA](http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/enzyme.php?ecno=3.2.1.20).

Comment: +1 I missed that (although there is a crystal structure with NAD+ that I couldn't find when I was writing It's [here](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?pdbId=3u95). Wierd thing is that apparently the NAD isn't being used as an oxidizing cofactor as it is  [reported to be unchanged in the reaction](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1367593100001356).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently not for [lactase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactase) and [β-galactosidase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-galactosidase), as one might expect for this sort of hydrolytic reaction. There are also Wikipedia entries for [maltase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltase), [sucrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucrase) and [trehalase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trehalase) with references you can follow up to check yourself.